# Can the cumsum function in NumPy decay while adding?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cumsum

I have an array of values `a = (2,3,0,0,4,3)`

```
y=0
for x in a:
  y = (y+x)*.95
```

Is there any way to use `cumsum` in `numpy` and apply the .95 decay to each row before adding the next value?

Answer (score 8):

You're asking for a simple [IIR Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response). Scipy's [lfilter()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) is made for that:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import lfilter

data = np.array([2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 3], dtype=float)  # lfilter wants floats

# Conventional approach:
result_conv = []
last_value = 0
for elmt in data:
    last_value = (last_value + elmt)*.95
    result_conv.append(last_value)

# IIR Filter:
result_IIR = lfilter([.95], [1, -.95], data)

if np.allclose(result_IIR, result_conv, 1e-12):
    print("Values are equal.")
```

Comment: I'd consider using `xx = np.array([2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 3], dtype=np.float64)` instead here

Comment: Valid point. I reran my code and it seems that the complaint from ``lfilter()`` came from a different problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you're only dealing with a 1D array, then short of scipy conveniences or writing a custom reduce ufunc for numpy, then in Python 3.3+, you can use `itertools.accumulate`, eg:

```
from itertools import accumulate

a = (2,3,0,0,4,3)
y = list(accumulate(a, lambda x,y: (x+y)*0.95))
# [2, 4.75, 4.5125, 4.286875, 7.87253125, 10.3289046875]
```

Answer (score 3):

Numba provides an easy way to [`vectorize`](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html) a function, creating a [universal function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) (thus providing [`ufunc.accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html)):

```
import numpy
from numba import vectorize, float64

@vectorize([float64(float64, float64)])
def f(x, y):
    return 0.95 * (x + y)

>>> a = numpy.array([2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 3])
>>> f.accumulate(a)
array([  2.        ,   4.75      ,   4.5125    ,   4.286875  ,
         7.87253125,  10.32890469])
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this can be done easily in NumPy alone, without using a loop.

One array-based idea would be to calculate the matrix M_ij = .95**i * a[N-j] (where N is the number of elements in a). The numbers that you are looking for are found by summing entries diagonally (with i-j constant). You could use thus use multiple `numpy.diagonal(…).sum()`.

The good old algorithm that you outline is clearer and probably quite fast already (otherwise you can use Cython).

Doing what you want through NumPy without a single loop sounds like wizardry to me. Hats off to anybody who can pull this off.